# Multidimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Today, I have a general question about storing objects/structs or some other values in a multidimensional array.

The actual scenario is as follows, but I might need similar solutions in many other places, which is why I want to ask you about the best-practice to this.

Suppose we have a side scrolling game. Now I need to store information about the cells of the world in some kind of 2-dimensional array, where 0:0 would be the home-position. At the beginning of the game, I generate a small area of the world, say from -10:-5 to 10:5. The player could move left or right (and sometimes up and down), so I have to generate more world information when he reaches the edges of the world. Now my question: How am I supposed to store a 2-dimensional array with varying extremes? Are there any best practices around how to do this? What would you do?

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Mostly a `vector<vector<T> >`.

Comment: @H2CO3 And how would I ideally keep track of the dimensions? Say my field at one point stretches from -101:-18 to 55:12 or something. How do I determine where the information to cell 0:0 is stored?

Comment: using a variable. Of type `size_t` or `int` or whatever. And `vector` knows its size.

Comment: @H2CO3: `vector<t>(dimension1*dimension2*dimension3*dimension4...)`, actually.

Comment: @H2CO3: Less allocations, no memory fragmentation/overhead, simpler resize.

Comment: @SigTerm If we are at it: `T (*arr)[Y][Z] = malloc(X * sizeof(*arr));` - even less overhead, even simpler resizing. Worth it? No. Good C++ style? No.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's a strawman. "Good style" is subjective. With number of dimensions > 2, you'll get overhead + slow resize because std::vector stores at least two integers and a pointer, and performs dynamic memory allocation on resize. And you'll get this extra info for every row, plane, cube "etc.". Unless every row/plane/cube/etc has different dimension, "recursive" vector is a bad idea. It is a warning sign - such usage of std::vector may also indicate that programmer does not understand difference between vector and array - an amateur. I wouldn't let somebody like that touch production code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38292/discussion-between-h2co3-and-sigterm)

Comment: @H2CO3: Let's say you have 8-dimensional array of ints, where each dimension is 2. Recursive vector will produce roughly 2^7*((1..2)*((sizeof(size_t))+(sizeof(T*)) overhead and roughly the same number of extra operations on every resize. On 32bit platform that'll be 1536 bytes of overhead, where actual data size will be 1024bytes. That's why types like that should be avoided for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @H2CO3: You might also want to check out [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_introduction). IF there's "real C++ way" to do it, this is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store it as an array, use a structure containing the coords and the value.

Then store those objects in a smarter structure - deque, list or tree depending on how they need to be searched.

Comment: Cool, I did not know about deques before, they sound pretty handy. Thx!

Comment: @LarsEbert if you are going to move in any direction (rather than just scroll in 1d) then look at trees.

Comment: Okay, I just googled "trees", I do not know what I expected... But seriously, I understandy the definition of a (binary-)tree but I have no idea how to store the world in a tree.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1**: use 1d array with `size == dimension1*dimension2*dimension3*....` and emulate multidimensional array like that. You will have to write your own resize code (should be easy)
**Solution #2**: Use sparse array. A `std::map<Coordinate, Value>` will do.
**Solution #3**: [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).
**Solution #4**: Don't store the world as N-dimensional array. Store objects as a list/deque/whatever, then use BSP tree, oct-trees, sweep and prune or space partitioning to quickly  locate objects in visible area.